# Snap.svg: Animation using mina() to draw lines along spiral

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I have an animation object, **AnimateJS**, in the example below. It functions to draw lines along a spiral.

I would like to convert it to Snap's mina(). I'm have a bit of difficulty in applying the various mina properties to make this happen.

Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://svgDiscovery.com/_SNP/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="setTimeout(runAnimLinear,1000)" >
<h4>Draw Spiraled Lines</h4>
<div style='width:90%;background-color:gainsboro;text-align:justify;padding:10px;border-radius:6px;'>
Use Snap to animate lines drawn along a spiral  </div>
<table><tr>
<td>
<table>
<tr><td colspan=2><b>This Example's AnimateJS Settings:</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>1. Smoothness</td><td>80 frames per second</td></tr>
<tr><td>2. Duration</td><td>3000 - runtime in ms</td></tr>
<tr><td>3. Range</td><td> 720 degrees : ending/maximum value</td></tr>
<tr><td>4. Output Equation</td><td><span style=color:blue>function</span> linear(p){return p} </td></tr>
<tr><td>5. Application Output </td><td><span style=color:blue>function</span> addToSpiral(angle)</td></tr>
</table><p></p>
The above values to be used in <b>mina(a, A, b, B, get, set, [easing])</b> <br>
 <textarea style=border-width:0px;width:400px;height:180px;>
 Parameters:
a - start slave number
A - end slave number
b - start master number (start time in general case)
B - end master number (end time in general case)
get - getter of master number (see mina.time)
set - setter of slave number
easing - oneasing function, default is mina.linear
 </textarea>
</td>
<td>
<div id="svgDiv" style='background-color:lightgreen;width:400px;height:400px;'>
<svg id="mySVG" width="400" height="400">
</svg>
</div>
<center><button disabled id=runAgainButton onClick=clearLines();runAnimLinear();this.disabled=true>run again</button></center>
</td>
</tr> </table>

</center>
<script>
var SNPsvg = Snap("#mySVG");
var SpiralG = SNPsvg.g().attr({id:'SpiralG',strokeWidth:1,stroke:'black' });

/*---generalized animate core function
Allows progress/output to follow a specific/customized equation(delta)
by: Ilya Kantor - http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation
*/
var AnimateJS=function(options){
    this.options=options
 var start = new Date
 var iT = setInterval(
 function(){
  var timePassed = new Date - start
  var progress = timePassed / options.duration
  if (progress > 1) progress = 1
  this.progress=progress
  var delta = options.delta(progress)
  options.output(delta)
  if (progress == 1)clearInterval(iT);
 },options.delay)
}
//--onload, and 'run again' button---
function runAnimLinear()
{
 var range=720 //--degrees: 2 revs---
 var FPS=80 //---Frames Per Second = smoothness--
 var delay=1000/FPS //---delay---
 var duration=3000 //---duration ms, 3 seconds---
 var delta=function linear(p){return p}//---linear---
 //---this animation---
 new AnimateJS({delay:delay,duration:duration,delta:delta,output:
 function(delta)//---output: delta=0.0 thru 1.0---
 {
  addToSpiral(range * delta )
  if(progress==1) //---finished---
  {
   runAgainButton.disabled=false
  }
 }})
}

//---fired at each output request---
function addToSpiral(angle)
{
 radius = Constant*angle;
 offsetX = radius*Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180);
 offsetY = radius*Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180);
 currentX = basePointX+offsetX;
 currentY = basePointY-offsetY;
 // add perpendicular line segments...
 lineX = lineHHLength*Math.cos(
  branches*angle*Math.PI/180);
 lineY = lineHHLength*Math.sin(
  branches*angle*Math.PI/180);

 fromX = currentX-lineX;
 fromY = currentY+lineY;
 destX = currentX+lineX;
 destY = currentY-lineY;

 lineNode = SNPsvg.line(fromX,fromY,destX,destY)
 SpiralG.append(lineNode);

 lineX = lineHHLength*Math.cos(
 branches*(angle+90)*Math.PI/180);
 lineY = lineHHLength*Math.sin(
 branches*(angle+90)*Math.PI/180);

 fromX = currentX-lineX;
 fromY = currentY+lineY;
 destX = currentX+lineX;
 destY = currentY-lineY;

 lineNode = SNPsvg.line(fromX,fromY,destX,destY)

 SpiralG.append(lineNode);
}
//--fired on 'run again' ---
function clearLines()
{
    SpiralG.clear()

}

//----spiral variables---
var basePointX    = 180.;
var basePointY    = 170.;
var currentX      = 0.;
var currentY      = 0.;
var offsetX       = 0.;
var offsetY       = 0.;
var radius        = 0.;
var minorAxis     = 12;
var majorAxis     = 20.;
var Constant      = 0.25;
var fromX         = 0.;
var fromY         = 0.;
var destX         = 0.;
var destY         = 0.;
var lineX         = 0.;
var lineY         = 0.;
var branches      = 3.;
var lineHVLength  = 2*minorAxis;
var lineHHLength  = 2*majorAxis;
var lineNode      = null;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need mina ? Snap has a generic animation method called Snap.animate() (docs [here](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.animate)). This doesn't act on a specific element (unlike element.animate() ); So you rarely need to get down and dirty with mina specifically (don't think I have ever needed to), but appreciate this isn't answering your question specifically.

The first 2 arguments are the start and end values (note, it can take an array of values as well I think to interpolate between). And these will get interpolated between (like the delta I think in the original code).

3rd argument is the function to call each time. The val/delta gets passed into this function.

4th argument is the easing (so mina.linear wanted here).

5th argument is the callback (so we reset the button to run the animation again if wanted)

The main core is this converted function..

```
function runAnimLinear() {
  var range=720 //--degrees: 2 revs---
  var duration=3000 //---duration ms, 3 seconds---

  Snap.animate(0, 1, function( delta ) {
    addToSpiral( range * delta )

  }, duration, mina.linear, function() { runAgainButton.disabled=false }  );
}
```

The rest I've left as is.

However, there are some issues here now depending if things like smoothness are really needed, so it's not quite the same. If so, I 'think' it would need another solution, which would be a bit more complex and I'm not sure if there would then be enough of a reason to not use the original. If it's a specific reason you need to use mina, maybe add that to the question.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/60fvy9jb/10/)

Here is kind of the same thing using mina to give an idea of how that works.

```
 var anim = mina( 0, 1, mina.time(), mina.time() + duration, mina.time, 
     function( delta ) { addToSpiral( range * delta )})

 //callback using eve, referencing the id of the animation from above
 eve.once("mina.finish." + anim.id, function () {
    runAgainButton.disabled=false
  });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/60fvy9jb/18/)

Comment: Thanks, Ian. I have about 20 nice animation examples using the AnimateJS object. I want to convert them to Snap, creating both the SVG and animation. I thought mina() would have been the simplest approach. Instead, I will use Snap.animation() as you have shown.

Comment: I've just added a similar example at the bottom as well now, just how you could use mina, as it's a bit of an unknown, and may help someone. I wouldn't normally use this (as it's more behind the scenes), but it has cropped up a couple of times.